# Access - linking to an external database

Tags: database, ms-access, external, linker-errors

I've linked to external databases before but all of sudden, I'm having trouble doing so.  I open my database, then click on External Data > ODBC Database.  when the pop-up appears, I click on the option that says "link to the data source by creating a linked table".  Next I click OK.  Then I click on the Machine Data Source tab.  Select my data source and click ok.  It looks like I'm going to get a pop up but it spins and spins and spins.  Then I see not responding.  This is a database created in Access 2000 that I opening in Access 2010.  The password on the Machine Data Source that I'm trying to use had expired sometime over the weekend.  I gave it a new password and checked that the password worked.  I'm not sure what is going on.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.........

Comment: Are any of the previously linked tables to that Machine Data source still working?

Comment: Did you test the Machine DSN in the ODBC administration? Be aware of http://superuser.com/questions/419832/how-can-i-open-the-32-bit-odbc-data-source-administrator-in-windows-7-64-bit if you are on 64bit Windows.

Comment: Why ODBC, if you link with ms access database , click ms access.

Comment: @random_answer_guy.........yes........other linked tables are still working.  There is another user that has a lock file on the database.  Our IT department is supposed to remove the lock.  I think this may be the cause of my issue.  Thanks.....

Comment: @Andre..........I did test the ODBC connection and it is working.  Another user has a lock file on the database.........

Comment: @M.Hassan.........I'm using an Access database but we are linking to  Teradata and Oracle databases in this Access database.  Thanks......